# Evaluate $S=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n}{i^n \cdot n}\right|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

> Evaluate
>   $$ S=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin n}{i^n \cdot n}\right|$$
>   where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

For this question, I did the following,

Let 
$$
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin n}{i^n \cdot n} \\
C &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos n}{i^n \cdot n} 
\end{align*}
$$
We have to evaluate $|S|$
$$\implies S = \Im{(C+iS)}=\Im\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{in}}{i^n \cdot n}$  $
However, due to the $n$ in the denominator, I cannot sum the series. If only it had been in the numerator I would've sum it as an A.G.P.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: aDo you know  series for $\ln(1+z)$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119043/where-does-the-sum-of-sinn-formula-come-from/1119079#1119079).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle I found this:

$$ S=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin n}{i^n \cdot n}\right|=$$

$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left|-ln(1+ie^{-i})+ln(1+ie^i)\right|$$

Comment: Can you please provide the details too? Thanks!

Comment: I was struggling with this in school and solved it together with my prof. You've write the sum easier

Comment: But can you at least provide some hints?

Comment: Use De Moivre and euler

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we add $C $and $iS$ together $$
\begin{aligned}
C+iS&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^i}{i}\right)^n \frac{1}{n}=-\ln \left(1-\frac{e^i}{i}\right) =-\ln \left(1+i e^i\right) \cdots(1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Secondly, we subtract $iS$ from $C$
$$
\begin{aligned}
C- & i S=-\ln \left(1-\frac{e^{-i}}{i}\right)=-\ln \left(1+i e^{-i}\right) \cdots(2)
\end{aligned}
$$
$(1)-(2)$ yields
$$
S=\frac{1}{2 i} \ln \left(\frac{1+i e^{-i}}{1+i e^i}\right)
$$
$$|S|= 
\frac{1}{2}\left|\ln \left(\frac{1+i e^{-i}}{1+i e^i}\right)\right|$$

We are now going to express $\frac{1+i e^{-i}}{1+i e^i}$ in polar form.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1+i e^{-i}}{1+i e^i}& =\frac{1+e^{\frac{\pi-2 }{2}i}}{1+e^{\frac{\pi+2}{2} i}}
= \frac{e^{\frac{\pi-2}{4} i}\left(e^{\frac{\pi-2}{4} i}+e^{-\frac{\pi-2}{4} i}\right)}{e^{\frac{\pi+2}{4} i}\left(e^{\frac{\pi+2}{4} i}+e^{-\frac{\pi+2}{4} i}\right)} = e^{-i} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi-2}{4}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi+2}{4}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then $$
\ln \left(\frac{1+i e^{-i}}{1+i e^i}\right) = \ln \left[\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi-2}{4}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi+2}{4}\right)}\right]-i
$$
We can now conclude that
$$
|S |=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\ln ^2\left[\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi-2}{4}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi+2}{4}\right)}\right]+1}
$$